# How to get word embedding from Fasttext model during model training?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, machine-learning

Generally while using static word embeddings like *Word2Vec*, *Glove*, *Fasttext* in a model (like [this](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/pretrained_word_embeddings/)), the vocabulary and embedding matrix are calculated before training the model. And Keras embedding layer is defined like :

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(
    num_tokens,
    embedding_dim,
    embeddings_initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(embedding_matrix),
    trainable=False,
)
```

How to build a pipeline where during model training a batch of input strings would go to model and get back a batch of embeddings? (in Word2Vec and Glove, this feature might not be much beneficial, but in Fasttext it would also give embeddings for OOV words too, which otherwise would go to UNK token in Embedding layer) In Keras, it become difficult as we can't access values of inputs because of it's graph mode property. How to turn these static model into keras layer which accept tensor input of string and give back tensor output of embeddings?